# How to Route all traffic outside WireGuard?

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I'm a newbie with networking and I'm trying to figure out one thing, so please bare with me if I'm missing anything the maybe it's obvoius for you guys ;)

I have an Rpi that act as a server, and I recently installed **DuckDNS** to be able to access some ports outside my local network and everything is working very fine, I recently started to use **Mullvad Vpn managed by WireGuard** and of course now I'm not able to access my ports anymore over duckdns.

All the mullvad vpn instruction to **route all the traffic outside the vpn** (i'm planning to use only SOCK5 for torrenting) points to OpenVpn.

So basically I can't figure out how to **setup wireguard to route all the traffic outside the VPN**, please can anyone explain me like I'm five please? Many thanks guys.

Comment: Please do not cross port to multiple forums.

Comment: @RonTrunk sorry I realize now that this is the optimal place for my question, I'll remove the other one in the other website.